# android bluetooth chat sample code crashes on the phone

Tags: android, crash, bluetooth, chat, sample

when i try to run android's bluetoothchat sample code on my phone(android 2.3.7), it turns on the bluetooth if off but then crashes immediately. Is there some problem in the sample code? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I figured that the Android Manifest file did not have "android:targetSdkVersion". I manually put it in and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

No problems in BluetoothChat...
I think that you have a different Android version 

or you have deleted the android permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```